# Speeding up Binary Integer programming model

Tags: scip

Can anyone give me some tips to make a binary integer programming model faster?
I currently have a model that runs well with very small amount of variables but as soon as I increase the number of variables in my model SCIP keeps running without giving me an optimal solution. I'm currently using SCIP with Soplex to find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the statistics (type `display statistics` in the interactive shell). Watch out for time consuming heuristics that don't find a solution and try disabling them. You should also play around with the parameters to find better suited settings for your instances (different branching rule or node selection). Without further information, though, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I'm very new to optimization so I don't know what most of the stuff in display statistics means. What exactly am I looking for? And what kind of information would you need to be able to help me?

Comment: As a first step you could try out different emphasis settings:  
    `SCIP> set emphasis`.  
In general parameter tuning can be quite difficult and time consuming. There is no recipe that works for every problem case.